# copy paste tab delimited results into excel file

Tags: excel, bash

I created a script to obtain data from a LDAP database and wrote it to a file with each value in a row separated by tabs. I then tried to copy and paste the contents of that file to excel, but it places all the tab delimited contents of each "column" within a row in the first column for that row, instead of placing each column of data in its own row within the excel file. Rows paste fine. 
For example lets take this mock first row

```
12121212 [] lastname,  firstname [] title [] phone [] manager
```

[] = where i tried to programmatically insert a tab in my data output

This puzzles me because I deliberately mad a function that removes the new line from my ldap search result, and adds a tab to the end of the data return for that column.  Here is the addTab function:

```
function addTab {
    res='           ' # res = "\t\tx"
    echo $1 | tr -d '\n'
    echo "$res" | tr -d '\n'
```

}

This is how I am calling the function (note $i is from the array of UIDs I use to search against via loop iteration):

```
addTab `getattrVal $i employeeNumber`
addTab `getattrVal $i employeeType`
addTab `getattrVal $i ou`
addTab `getattrVal $i managerEmployeeNumber`
```

And here is the code for the getattrVal function

```
function getattrVale {
    /opt/bin/ldapsearch -QLLLZZH ldap://${VIP}:389/ -b $1 $2 | grep "$2:" |awk '{ print $2 }'
```

}

I've even tried using the column command to generate nice and even outputted columns (i.e. column -t bashCreatedTabFile.txt) and I still can not paste the contents as desired within the Excel spread sheet.

I realize there are better ways to probably do this, but I think understanding why this is not working is important to my progress.

Comment: If I understand your question.. no. I simply write stdout to a file and then open the file and copy the contents of the file and paste into the excel file. So my presumption is I should be copying all the content with the included tabs. But it appears the tabs are just spaces..

Comment: it places all the contents of each column within a row in the first column for that row. I will update the post with a example.

Comment: Does "od -xc bashCreatedTabFile.txt" show tabs and newlines where expected? Also, if you try to import the txt file (rather than cut&paste) does it detect the column separator correctly? You might also try to paste into a new text file and then see if that looks correct (is this Windows? maybe the cut&paste is converting tabs to spaces?)

Comment: I'm not sure what I am looking at when using the od -xc file command, but I'm going to guess its not right. can't really paste the output in this comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem. This isn't the best solution, but it does work.

Change your delimiter to a comma (`,`). Copy the text as you would normally and paste into Excel. It will probably still be one column. Highlight the column, go to Data > Text to Columns in Excel.

Make sure the data type is "delimited," and select "comma" as the delimiter. I'm not sure why, but the same things doesn't seem to work with tabs.

http://www.wikihow.com/Copy-Paste-Tab-Delimited-Text-Into-Excel

Answer (score 0):

Try do it with html output of table.

Like using

```
print(tabulate(table, headers, tablefmt="html"))

<table>
<tbody>
<tr><th>item  </th><th style="text-align: right;">  qty</th></tr>
<tr><td>spam  </td><td style="text-align: right;">   42</td></tr>
<tr><td>eggs  </td><td style="text-align: right;">  451</td></tr>
<tr><td>bacon </td><td style="text-align: right;">    0</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```